# Applying Search/Filter Dropdown For Django CreateView

Tags: python, django, drop-down-menu

I am trying to apply a [search/filter in dropdown menu](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_dropdown.asp) on the field that has a selector (in this case the "item_selector") which can easily contains with at least a thousand entry.

## models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Model_Model01(models.Model):
    item_selector = (
        ("item_0001", "item_0001"),
        ...,
        ...,
        ("item_9999", "item_9999"),
        )

    item_01 = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True, blank = True, choices = item_selector)

    def __unicode__(self): # or __str___
        return self.item_01
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Model_Model01

class Form_Model01(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Model_Model01
        fields = ["item_01"]
```

## views.py

```
from .models import Model_Model01
from .forms import Form_Model01
from django.views.generic import CreateView

class View_Model01_CV(CreateView):
    form_class = Form_Model01

    def form_valid(self, form):
        instance = form.save(commit = False)
        instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(View_Model01_CV, self).form_valid(form)
```

## html

```
<form method = "POST" action = "" enctype = "multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.item_01 }}
    <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
</form>
```

I wondering if there is a way to do this in Django, either using Django 3rd party app or with a Bootstrap.

Comment: Did you try to use jQuery and autocomplete tool? Sounds more relevant in my ears. Take a look at https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: @PanosAngelopoulos I have just tried using autocompletetool, and I am still not sure how to make it work.

Comment: It's fine. I have found the solution using this app: http://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Great ! @Fxs7576